# How to avoid the program exit after Connection Refused with Boost Asio and C/C++

Tags: c++, exception, boost-asio

At the moment, I'm using Boost Asio in order to connect to a server via TCP.

I use a conditional case to decide if the application has to start or not a connection with the server; it works great but the problem is that if I try to connect to the server when the server is down then the application crash giving this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  Connection refused
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
    case CONNECTION:
 // Connect to the server
 using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
 boost::asio::io_service io_service;
 tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
 tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), server, boost::lexical_cast<string>(porta));
 tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
 tcp::socket s(io_service); 
 s.connect(*iterator);
```

I'd like to keep alive my application with its normal behavior and only prompt a warning about the connection failed.

How can I handle this exception?

Answer (score 9):

You should use `try ... catch` blocks. They work this way :

```
try
{
    s.connect(*iterator);
}
catch (boost::system::system_error const& e)
{
    std::cout << "Warning: could not connect : " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to catch **everything** when you can catch only what is expected ?

Comment: Perhaps a poorly choosen example so. It is not clear from your answer that the OP should catch `boost::system::system_error`. Beginners reading your answer might even think that it is a good practice to "catch everything" while it is actually a terrible thing.

Comment: If you catch all exceptions then how did you decide that you "could not connect"? May be you "could not allocate memory"? Or "referenced invalid memory address" or "passed invalid parameter (to some function somewhere)"?

Comment: @Heandel: Way clearer. However, you might also edit it again to catch by **const reference**: as it stands, your code might lead to unwanted slicing.

Comment: @ereon: Done, feel free to edit more things to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your advices and tips.

The problem is that i use "s" in some other code parts to write or receive information from server, so if it doesn't connect the s pointer is empty and then the application crash with "Broken pipe error" even if i trap the excpetion. I have to try and catch the same exception also with the read and write functions?

Comment: Perfect!
Now it works well!

Thanks a lot for your advices.
I begin to understand of try..catch works!

Answer (score 7):

According to documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/connect/overload1.html), on failure `connect` throws `boost::system::system_error`. So you need to wrap around your code in a `try...catch` block and catch the above mentioned exception. Or if you don't want to use the exceptions you can use the other overload described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/connect/overload2.html) which returns an error code on error.